# refreshing terminal window's view of a recreated directory

Tags: bash, terminal

I use a program that recreates a certain directory structure each time it is run, then populates it with all kinds of data.

I keep a terminal window "open at" one of the subdirectories of that directory, where I wish to list and browse the data being created.

However in that window, each time the program re-runs, listing the current directory shows 0 files - bash isn't up-to-date on the directory - presumably because it had been recreated. My workaround is to `cd` again to the same directory, but is there something else that will maintain the shell window's correct view of the recreated directory at all times?

Currently I found `cd .` being the simplest workaround, but of course it needs to be used every time. Would be nice being able to avoid that alltogether.

If relevant, this is Ubuntu.

Comment: Better may be: `cd ..; watch "ls subdir"`

Comment: @JeffSchaller you might want to post `watch ls subdir` as an answer

Comment: If the existing answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; thank you!

Comment: Thanks for reawakening this post and thanks for the answer few years ago, but no, the provided answer was a nice suggestion, but I do not consider it a solution. Not sure why you are trying to press on that, but thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I use a program that recreates a certain directory structure each time
>   it is run ... Is there something else that will maintain the shell
>   window's correct view of the recreated directory at all times?

Not directly, no. Your shell is in no-man's-land after re-running your program. The safest solution (if you insist on removing the top-level directory) is to keep your shell `cd`'d above it (`cd ..`) and run something like:

```
watch "ls subdir"
```

...to have it show you updates as they happen.